# Is there any method for implementing scroll for cdk drag drop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, angular7, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have implemented cdk drag and drop in my application.

I am working in angular 7.

Angular material version is 7.3.7 and cdk version is 7.3.7.

My problem is while dragging a item in cdkDropList, if the list is lenghty one with overflow, then the item cant drag out of the current view.

I searched for a lot of solutions, and reached on some findings.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13588

It says that the issue is with version. So one solution is to update the material and cdk versions.

But I have lot of dependencies with angular 7 and can't update the whole application.

So is there any method for implementing this on current application without updating the application?

Any help would be appreciable.